# PHP and 2 <option> lists, why the $_POST() is not using the name tag...?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the following code (https://codepen.io/enogrob/pen/OwjrGy) in my form and running into an issue with the **$_POST()** not pulling the name"" tag, it references the value"" tag which in this case isn't helpful.

The 1st SELECT:

```
<select id="canvasSelect" name="canvasSelect" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <option>choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Canvas 1</option>
    <option value="2">Canvas 2</option>
</select>
```

The select code looks like this:

```
<select id="colorSelect" name="colorSelect" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <option>choose...</option>
    <option name="6" value="1">WHITE</option>
    <option name="7" value="1">BLUE</option>
    <option name="8" value="1">GOLD</option>
    <option name="9" value="2">BLUE</option>
    <option name="10" value="2">GOLD</option>
</select>
```

and the java script implementation like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var $select1 = $( '#canvasSelect' ),
            $select2 = $( '#colorSelect' ),
            $options = $select2.find( 'option' );
            
        $select1.on( 'change', function() {
            $select2.html( $options.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
            $('#colorSelect').val(''); //add this line for blank selection
        } ).trigger( 'change' );

</script>
```

Is there a way to fix this or is there a better way to drive a second select from another ??

Comment: Since the name attribute is not available for an option that name value is never sent to the server.  I suggest you use the name value of the option as the actual value instead.  Then remove that attribute from each option.  I don't understand why you have multiple options with the same value anyway.

Comment: I forgot to add the 1st SELECT... I've updated the question with that info. Essentially the user is to select a Canvas 1st then be limited to what colors can be SELECTED from the 2nd SELECT. So, I understand that the NAME option is not available to SELECT ...  but using the actual value of (6,7,8,9,10) is not descriptive for the end user to select from..

Comment: So, select2 will show the value of select1 selectedIndex?  So, how is it helpful to the user to see select2 with an option of 1 or 2?  Maybe you need to show selected text instead?  You didn't show the HTML for select1.

Comment: I've edited the code for HTML SELECT 1 and 2... ultimately I need an ID number from both SELECTS not text. Since the 2nd SELECT is driven from the first via JAVAScript, it "filters" on value"", but I really need what is in name"" (5,6,7,8,9,10, etc.) Is there a way to accomplish that??

Comment: "but I really need what is in name"" (5,6,7,8,9,10, etc.)" ... just to add some more clarity "Name" is a second ID and "Value" is the first ID.

Comment: To close the loop on this question... I was able to successfully get the results that I needed by adding a custom attribute. I'll edit the original question with the code used for future reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a custom attribute on the 2nd SELECT combined with a hidden input using the following:

```
<select id="colorSelect" name="colorSelect" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <option>choose...</option>
    <option colorID="6" value="1">WHITE</option>
    <option colorID="7" value="1">BLUE</option>
    <option colorID="8" value="1">GOLD</option>
    <option colorID="9" value="2">BLUE</option>
    <option colorID="10" value="2">GOLD</option>
</select><input type="hidden" id="custAtt" name="colorID" />
```

and the script that goes with it:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#colorSelect").change(function(){
            var option = $('option:selected', this).attr('colorID');
            $('#custAtt').val(option);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, but the data sent via a POST for a form containing a `<select>` tag will contain the `name` **of that `<select>` tag**, and the `value` of whatever selected `<option>` is selected.

The `name` attribute that you are adding to the option is not available to the server.

If you were to submit the form in your example, the payload sent to the server will be exactly:

```
colorSelect=1
```

Independently of the WHITE, BLUE or GOLD option being selected.

Comment: The SCRIPT still doesn't seem to return the value="" (6,7,8,9,10) of the SELECT only the "this.value" which I think is "1" or "2" depending on the selection of the 1st SELECT.. ?

Comment: How about using a custom attribute, is that an option?

Comment: You tagged the question `php`, and you mention that you are reading the `$_POST`. Nothing you do in JavaScript is going to change the fact that the form will post only the selected `value`. Try changing the question title, and formulating a clear JavaScript related question if that is your intent.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a select element, the key=value pair that is submitted is:

```
nameOfSelectElement=valueOfSelectedOption
```

There is no `name` attribute for `<option>` elements.

If you want to encode multiple pieces of data, then put it all in the value. e.g.

```
<select name="colorSelect">
    <option value="1-6">WHITE</option>
    <option value="1-7">BLUE</option>
</select>
```

… and then parse it on the server:

```
$value = explode("-", $_POST['colorSelect'])
```

Then `$value[0]` will be `1` and `$value[1]` will be `6` or `7`.

---

Alternatively, use a unique value and then look it up on the server.

```
<select name="colorSelect">
    <option>WHITE</option>
    <option>BLUE</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$values = [
    WHITE => [
        name => "1",
        value => "6"
    ],
    BLUE => [
        name => "1",
        value => "7"
    ],
];

$name = $values[ $_POST['colorSelect'] ]["name"]
$value = $values[ $_POST['colorSelect'] ]["value"]
```

Comment: I don't think your first option would work as that would break the filtering for the 2nd SELECT. The value"" needs to be tied to the value of the first SELECT in order to perform a filter on it. The problem was solved using a custom attribute.. thank you for your input though.